# In React When I wrapped App component inside a Context Provider component nothing got rendered but a white blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-context

4.[This is Context Provider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQQZI.png)
3.[This is the <h1> element which is out side the Context Provider component, It got rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSInj.png)
2.[This is App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyiDw.png)
1.[This is index.js file, where I wrapped App component inside Context provider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYpdg.png)

When I wrapped APP component inside UserProvider component I got white blank screen and also no errors in the console by the way. But when I have removed UserProvider component, every thing is rendering normally and I know that something is wrong with UserProvider component so I added a  element outside the UserProvider component, it is rendering fine. You can see everything in the above images clearly. Please help me I got stuck.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You missing a return in the Context Provider.